# invoking favorites tab of native phone app in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

is it possible to invoke the native phone app favorites tab into my app ? or i have to reproduce same thing  manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't get the favorites tab into your application. I don't think it is possible to get the list of favorites from any official API so you have to implement it all. That is, the list of favorites in your app can't be synced to the list of favorites in the native phone app.